# Searching a directory for two different file formats

Tags: python, operating-system

I have the following method:

```
def file_match(self, fundCodes):
    # Get a list of the files
    files = os.listdir(self.unmappedDir)
    # loop through all the files and search for matching file
    for check_fund in fundCodes:
        # Format of file to look for
        file_match = 'unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=check_fund, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)
        # look in the unmappeddir and see if there's a file with that name
        if file_match in files:
            # if there's a match, load unmapped positions as etl
            return self.read_file(file_match)
```

The method would seek for files that can match this type of format:

`unmapped_A-AGEI_2018-07-01_2018-07-09.csv` or
`unmapped_PWMA_2018-07-01_2018-07-09.csv`

NOTE: The `fundCodes` argument would be an array of "fundCodes"

Now, I want it to be able to look for another type of format, which would be the following:

`citco_unmapped_trades_2018-07-01_2018-07-09` I'm having a little trouble trying to figure out how to re-write the function so it can look for two possible formats and if it finds one then move on to the `self.read_file(file_match)` method. (If it finds both, I might have to do some error handling). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this when I was looking for answers about something else. Keep in mind I wrote this in a couple of minutes. I am sure it can be improved. You should be able to copy and paste this and run it. You will just have to create the files or drop the script in the same directory as the files. Feel free to modify it the way you want. This may not be the best solution but it should work. I wrote this so you can test it immediately. You will just have to modify it so that it runs correctly in your program. If you need me to elaborate please comment below.

```
    import os
    def file_search(formats, fund_codes):
        files = os.listdir()

        for fund in fund_codes:
            for fmt in formats:
                file_match = fmt.format(fund=fund[0], start=fund[1], end=fund[2])
                if file_match in files:
                    print(file_match)

    formats = ['unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv', 'citco_unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv']
    fund_codes = [['PWMA', '2018-07-01', '2018-07-09'], ['A-AGEI', '2018-07-01', '2018-07-09'], ['trades', '2018-07-01', '2018-07-09']]
    file_search(formats, fund_codes)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many various approaches that can be used to do this, it depends, in particular, on your possible further enhancements. The easiest and quite straightforward way is to make a list of allowed filenames and check it one by one:

```
file_matches = [
    'unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=check_fund, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate),
    'citco_unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=check_fund, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)
]

# look in the unmappeddir and see if there's a file with that name
for file_match in file_matches:
    if file_match in files:
        # if there's a match, load unmapped positions as etl
        return self.read_file(file_match)
```